# Rails responding to Javascript request even though format.js is not on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a standard, scaffolded Rails 5.1 (or 5.0) controller, you get this on the create action:

```
def create
    @test = Test.new(test_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @test.save
        format.html { redirect_to @test, notice: 'Test was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @test }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @test.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

As you see, there is no `format.js` there.

But if you add `remote: true` to the form (or, in Rails 5.1, you remove the `local: true` which will use the new default which is to post via ajax), the form works: the browser will send a post via xhr and redirect to the newly created record.

Looking at dev tools, I see that the response for the form submission was a 200 OK with the following content:

```
Turbolinks.clearCache()
Turbolinks.visit("http://localhost:3000/tests/10", {"action":"replace"})
```

Console also indicates it was processed by Javascript:

`Started POST "/tests" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-18 09:38:25 -0300
Processing by TestsController#create as JS`

The question is then: how is Rails handling this response/redirect for the JS request if there's no `format.js` in the controller?

I'm all in for Rails magic but I want to know how this works, and I haven't seen this '*fallback the JS request to the format.html block*' documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the code that is generating that response comes from the `turbolinks-rails` gem.

https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-rails/blob/v5.0.1/lib/turbolinks/redirection.rb#L14

From the linked code it looks like turbolinks prepares a js response when `redirect_to` is called, the request is `XHR`, not a `GET` request, and `turbolinks: false` was not provided to the `redirect_to` call.

Turbolinks overrides ActionController `redirect_to` when the gem is present and `app.config.turbolinks.auto_include` is truthy.

```
def redirect_to(url = {}, options = {})
  turbolinks = options.delete(:turbolinks)

  super.tap do
    if turbolinks != false && request.xhr? && !request.get?
      visit_location_with_turbolinks(location, turbolinks)
    else
      if request.headers["Turbolinks-Referrer"]
        store_turbolinks_location_in_session(location)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is intended and implemented by `ActionView::LookupContext`:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb#L251

```
# Override formats= to expand ["*/*"] values and automatically
# add :html as fallback to :js.
def formats=(values)
  if values
    values.concat(default_formats) if values.delete "*/*".freeze
    if values == [:js]
      values << :html
      @html_fallback_for_js = true
    end
  end
  super(values)
end
```

There is an open PR to change this behavior, but it's stalling now:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15224

There was some discussion about this other PR:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5892